# Unable to work with Tensorflow old as well as new version

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to understand how Tensorflow works by executing some of the codes present as samples in the online tutorials. However, when I execute the code, I run into either of the 2 problems below:-

```
1. module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
2. module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'unpack'
```

I had tensorflow version 1.14 installed earlier in Anaconda. I was not able to upgrade to tensorflow 2.0. So I unistalled Anaconda and did a reinstallation along with the newer version of tensorflow. I did this primalrily because several of the function definitions had changed. Order of inputs and attribute names like *unpack* for example. But with the newer version even *placeholder* is not being recognised. I checked online and used *tf.disable_v2_behavior()* to use the previous version even though I have the latest version installed. But then I get the naming error again. I am really confused how to proceed. I have been at it since hours. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you try  
    `import tensorflow as tf` and 
    `print (tf.__version__)` and let us know what output you get in your code?

Comment: I get 2.0.0. I checked my current installation using that. Now I find that, I can't even run tf.Session(). I think my previous installation is somehow messing with the current one.